# how to STOP previous MediaPlayer.create(this,resID) and run next MediaPlayer.create(this,resID)

Tags: java, android

**Code is working ok for run media, my problem how to stop previous created MediaPlayer.create(this,resID), if i runned it from AdapterList and have only one  void (it is more comfortably for me)**

```
  public void mp3start (){
    String nameofmp3 = "sura"+String.valueOf(AdapterList.nummp3+1);
    int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(nameofmp3, "raw", getPackageName());
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
    mediaPlayer.start();

}
```

Comment: you can use singleton pattern to control media player creation.

Comment: Decision: if(mediaPlayer!=null) mediaPlayer.reset();